# How to chase and analyze the cause of a crash

Tags: 20.04, crash

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on my laptop for few months. I've had a crash just ago which forced me to power off the pc via power button. Only the mouse pointer was moving and it was stuttering as well. There were 4 open tabs on Firefox at that moment. I want to know the reason of this crash. Is it possible?

I am suspecting that it is caused by a hard drive failure. Is there any log file to check for that?

```
bwd@bwd-SATELLITE-Radius-14-L40W-C-102:~$ ls -al /var/crash
total 8
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Nis 16 16:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root     4096 Tem 31  2020 ..
bwd@bwd-SATELLITE-Radius-14-L40W-C-102:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7,7Gi       1,2Gi       4,8Gi       366Mi       1,7Gi       5,9Gi
Swap:         2,0Gi          0B       2,0Gi
bwd@bwd-SATELLITE-Radius-14-L40W-C-102:~$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

[image]

```
bwd@bwd-SATELLITE-Radius-14-L40W-C-102:~$ grep -i swap /etc/fstab
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
bwd@bwd-SATELLITE-Radius-14-L40W-C-102:~$ sudo swapon -s
[sudo] password for bwd: 
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file        2097148 0   -2
bwd@bwd-SATELLITE-Radius-14-L40W-C-102:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
5.00
```

This is a Toshiba Satellite Radius 14 L40W-C-102 laptop.

Comment: Note the time of a crash. Check for error messages around that time in /var/log/syslog. If you don't know how to read /var/log/syslog (or how to use `grep` to filter the log) then look it up. If you suspect hard drive failure, then look up how to run a SMART test on your hard drive(s).

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and screenshot(s) of the `Disks` app **SMART Data & Tests** data window. This is a scrollable window and might requires two screenshots. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema All ready. Please check.

Comment: @AndrewHarlan Thanks for the data. You didn't have a "crash", but rather, a "freeze". The disk looks fine. Did this occur after using the computer for a while after a reboot? Show me `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `sudo swapon -s`. Also show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model of your computer or motherboard.

Comment: @heynnema Yes, it was a freeze. I think it happened after few hours I switched on the computer. Disk looks fine but sometimes I hear it's spinning on and off and sound of magnetic head clicks constantly. I'll add requested info to my question now.

Comment: @AndrewHarlan That hard disk noise usually means that the disk is bad... but let's try a few more things before we go there. I tried to find a BIOS update, but the web site didn't like your model #, so look at the tags and see if you find a Pxxxxxxx number, or a serial #. Also, start the `Disks` app again, go to **SMART Data & Tests**, and  go ahead and run the tests. Report back.

Comment: @AndrewHarlan Let's look at syslog for disk errors. Do `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*` and copy/paste that output to paste.ubuntu.com, and give me the URL and I'll take a look for you.

Comment: @heynnema it's here... https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DWQQHfgGy2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124233/discussion-between-heynnema-and-andrew-harlan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SWAP**

Let's increase your 2G /swapfile to 4G.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 8G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**BIOS**

Toshiba Satellite Radius 14 L40W-C-102 (PSLZAE-00R00STE)

You have BIOS version 5.00.

**Note**: This is a Turkish model/serial, and BIOS updates are not available at the U.S. site. You'll have to search at the Toshiba Turkish web site for BIOS updates.

**Disks**

The SMART Data looks good.

Run the SMART self-tests.

**Note**: SMART short self-test ran fine

**Note**: Clicking noises from the disk usually indicate a hardware problem.

Answer (score 1):

At a teminal type `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i shutdown`
For older syslog type `cat /var/log/syslog.1 | grep -i shutdown`
And you can swap out the word **shutdown** for other words like **mozilla** etc.
You'll get more that you want but if you know exactly when it happened it might give you a lead.

Comment: At the time of the crash I have following entries.

Edit: Sorry, I can't post it here. It is too long. I don't know what to look for here and I have no results when I send the command for mozilla.